# OpenGL ES 2.0 and glError 0x502 ? (using Vuforia)

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

Can someone please advise what's wrong with the following OpenGL ES 2.0 code? I'm using the Vuforia Augmented Reality SDK and I want to draw line with one end one colour, then fading into the colour of the other end.

```
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, line_vertices_buffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, line_colours_buffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, colorHandle, "color");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures.get(2).mTextureID[0]);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, vuforiaAppSession.getProjectionMatrix().getData(), 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(colorHandle, 0);
    GLES20.glLineWidth(30);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, 2 + line_vertices_array.size());
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);
```

The gradient doesn't appear. Ubuntu Eclipse LogCat states the following error which is related to the `glUniform1i(colorHandle, 0)` command near the end of the code.

```
06-06 09:13:57.340: E/Vuforia_Sample_Applications(14175): After operation UserDefinedTargets renderFrame got glError 0x502
06-06 09:13:57.390: W/Adreno-ES20(14175): <__load_uniform_int:351>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

The shaders are given by:

```
String frameVertexShader = " \n" + "attribute vec4 vertexPosition; \n"
    + "attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord; \n" + "\n"
    + "varying vec2 texCoord; \n" + "\n"
    + "uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix; \n" + "\n"
    + "void main() \n" + "{ \n"
    + "gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertexPosition; \n"
    + "texCoord = vertexTexCoord; \n" + "} \n";

String frameFragmentShader = " \n" + "precision mediump float; \n" + "\n"
    + "varying vec2 texCoord; \n" + "\n"
    + "uniform sampler2D texSampler2D; \n" + "uniform vec4 keyColor; \n"
    + "\n" + "void main() \n" + "{ \n"
    + "vec4 texColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord); \n"
    + "gl_FragColor = keyColor * texColor; \n" + "} \n" + "";
```

I tried changing "color" to "keyColor" in my main code, but still get the error, i.e.

```
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, colorHandle, "color");
```

to

```
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, colorHandle, "keyColor");
```

I also made sure my buffer has 4 floats for RGBA since the fragment shader seems to expect this in `keyColor`.

NB Vuforia does seem to use ByteBuffer even for the float array, and then we use putFloat into the ByteBuffer, e.g.

```
    line_colours_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 4 * (2 + line_vertices_array.size()));
    line_colours_buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(1f);   // colour for line start
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(0f);
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(0f);
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(0.5f);
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(0f);   // colour for line start
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(1f);
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(0f);
    line_colours_buffer.putFloat(0.5f);

    ... + other lines as required.
```

Comment: The shaders do not contain an attribute "color" or "colorkey". In addition, you are binding an attribute to a location, but then try to set a uniform.

Comment: Thanks. But the shader does have keyColor ? I will have another play with the code given your other comments.

Comment: It contains a UNIFORM called keyColor, but not an attribute. And it's of type vec4 not int, so you habe to use a uniform4f* command to set it